# Cannot login to Linux with AD account and /bin/bash

Tags: shell, login, active-directory, sssd

I have configured everything necessary to log in with an AD account into Linux (Kerberos v5, SSSD, Samba and NTP), but when I connect with Putty to the server, the default shell that starts is `/bin/sh`.

I use a Mac Mini PowerPC and have installed SSSD version 1.13.4.

`/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = <FQDN>
reconnection_retries = 3
debug_level = 5

[nss]
default_shell = /bin/bash
debug_level = 5

[pam]
debug_level = 5

[domain/<FQDN>]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
default_shell = /bin/bash
override_homedir = /home/%u
debug_level = 5
```

I have this error:

```
[e]0bash
daniel.luna@devsrv2:~$ exit
exit
[e]0
```

and

```
login as: daniel.luna
daniel.luna<FQDN>'s password:
...
Last login: Thu May 17 11:35:51 2018 from
-sh: 24: u@h:: not found
[e]0
```

I need to configure everything so that I start bash by default, any help?

Comment: Configure shell in LDAP or configured it in a template in smb.conf. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 2):

What is your user's `loginShell` LDAP attribute?  This is typically what determines a user's shell when using LDAP/AD backends for SSSD.

You can verify a user's shell with a couple different tools.

Using `getent passwd`, the shell will be the 7th (last) field:

```
[hendrenj@pitserver ~]$ getent passwd hendrenj
hendrenj:*:152370:829:hendrenj:/home/hendrenj:/bin/bash
```

Or using `sssctl user-checks`, you can grep for the shell:

```
[hendrenj@pitserver ~]$ sudo sssctl user-checks hendrenj 2>&1 | grep shell
 - shell: /bin/bash
```

If the reported shell is something other than `/bin/bash`, you will need to update the shell attribute on the LDAP side of things.  If the reported shell is `/bin/bash`, then the problem is local.  Either you have a configuration error in your `sssd.conf`, or `/bin/bash` is not what it claims to be, or the user's `.bashrc` file is exec'ing a different shell, or some other local problem.